# Can we use downloaded android source code at another system

Tags: android

I downloaded the android source code in my laptop, my friend also need that. if i just copy it and give to him, is it work for him?
if yes so how could we do that.

We are using different OS as I am using Ubuntu10.04 & he has 12.04 so is it make any problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would assume so, but if you used git or subversion make sure you get the hidden folder for it. Android is not Ubuntu, and the source code is the same everywhere. This should not be a problem unless you plan to run Android on the system, it might run slower on an older one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but Do you know how to do it.??

Comment: You could probably copy the folder you downloaded the code to onto a thumbdrive or an external hard drive, and then copy the same folder off the drive onto your friend's computer. However you should be careful with using external hard drives because older versions of Ubuntu might not be able to read them, so I recommend a large thumbdrive/USB drive/flash drive.